# Join 2 tables/files (csv or excel) in 1 (with rows order=Id column from table 1 for the new table joined) and same heads of columns in the 2 tables

Tags: r

For example to transform or join these 2 tables/files in 1 (with rows order=Id from file/table 1 for the new table joined) and the same heads of columns from the 2 tables:
File/table 1:
[image]

File/table 2:
[image]

Comment: What is your question? What did you try that did not work? Errors or undesired results? Also, please avoid [screenshot of data/code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451). See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

You only have screenshots of your data, but I'm guessing you want this?

```
DF1 <-read.csv("table1.csv")
DF2 <-read.csv("table2.csv")

combined <- merge(DF1, DF2, by="Id")
```

Comment: Yes mikephel, that's is what I was looking for. Very well your solution.

Comment: Could you please click the checkmark underneath the score of that answer? It will help others find this answer in the future if they have the same question.